# Determine point a certain distance away from a line

Tags: c++, math, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

This is more of a math question than an actual programming question but since I'm using `C++` and `COCOS2D-X`, I opted to post it here.

I'm using `CCBezierTo` to create a bezier movement that the sprite `mySprite`runs. The `CCBezierConfig` struct accepts three points (`CCPoint`s): `controlPoint_1`, `controlPoint_2`, and `endPoint`. The two `controlPoint`s are the points in which the bezier will curve.

Now here's the question. The `controlPoint`s which I need to create a curve are unknown and can only be acquired by doing a bit of math. These are the variables that are known. Please refer to the diagram below.

```
A = The start point of the curve
B = The end point of the curve
Line AB = The line created by connecting A and B together
L = The distance between A and B/The length of Line AB
D = The distance between the line and the unknown points
```

I am trying to look for X and Y. I have already achieved a bit of this but only when the line is either horizontal or vertical:

```
// From left to right:
ccBezierConfig bezierConfig;
bezierConfig.controlPoint_1 = CCPointMake( A.x + ( L * 0.25f ), A.y + aCertainHeight );
bezierConfig.controlPoint_2 = CCPointMake( A.x + ( L * 0.75f ), A.y - aCertainHeight );
bezierConfig.endPoint = B;

/** CCPointMake( x, y ) is a macro that creates a CCPoint object, which is a point on a plane. 
    It accepts two float values determining the X and Y position of the point.**/

// From top to bottom:
ccBezierConfig bezierConfig;
bezierConfig.controlPoint_1 = CCPointMake( A.x + aCertainWidth, A.y - ( L * 0.25f ) );
bezierConfig.controlPoint_2 = CCPointMake( A.x - aCertainWidth, A.y - ( L * 0.25f ) );
bezierConfig.endPoint = B;
```

How can I get X and Y if the line is diagonal?

Case 1: Line starts from left to right
[image: Case 1: Line starts from left to right]

Case 2: Line starts from upper left to lower right
[image: Case 2: Line starts from upper left to lower right]

Case 3: Line starts from upper right to lower left
[image: Case 3: Line starts from upper right to lower left]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: All of this is simple if you learn a little bit about the mathematics of vectors.

Comment: I would love to learn more about Vectors. I am currently looking for nice books and links but those that I find are mostly libraries.

Comment: @Lance: this seems quite fun: http://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra/v/linear-algebra--introduction-to-vectors. In computing, watch out for the fact that the *collection* called `std::vector` in C++ is different from the mathematical concept of a vector.

Comment: @SteveJessop Yes, I am aware of the `std::vector` since I've been using them a lot. Will definitely check out that link.

Comment: @Lance: OK, well try to forget about `std::vector` while you're learning what a vector is in mathematics. The two concepts have some similarities but aren't the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1: compute the vector from A to B, call it `v`.

Step 2: compute a vector perpendicular to that vector, and with unit length. Call it `w`. In general `(-y, x)` and `(y, -x)` are both perpendicular to `(x, y)`. The former points "to the left" and the latter "to the right".

Step 3: compute `X` as `A + 0.25 * v + D_1 * w` and similar for `Y`.

I think this all works out as:

```
// Using a "point" type for a vector is dodgy, but it works.
w = CCPointMake((B.y - A.y) / L, -(B.x - A.x) / L);
X = CCPointMake(
    0.75 * A.x + 0.25 * B.x + D_1 * w.x,
    0.75 * A.y + 0.25 * B.y + D_1 * w.y,
);
Y = CCPointMake(
    0.25 * A.x + 0.75 * B.x + D_2 * w.x,
    0.25 * A.y + 0.75 * B.y + D_2 * w.y,
);
```

or similar.

If cocos2d has a separate type for 2-D vectors, use that, you might find that you can write expressions like `(B - A)/L` and so on.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Cocos2d-x (as far as I know) has no support for complicated vector methods. Though there are macros like ccpAdd( ) and ccpSub( ) which allows adding and subtracting of two CCPoint objects respectively.

Comment: @Lance: sounds like it expects you to use the point type to represent vectors, then. In which case "the vector from A to B" is `ccpSub(B, A)` and so on.